# Problem getting custom payment gateway setup on Magento Cloud

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud

So I am working on a custom payment gateway extension. It installs and works beautifully in my test server. Right now I'm trying to get it install on Magento Cloud.

I follow their installation instructions, and can see that my database changes are present, but my payment gateway doesn't show up in the store configuration.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/apruve/apruve-magento2

Any ideas?

Comment: Does that have any system.xml file present inside etc/adminhtml directory?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to include a link to my source code on Github.

Comment: Are you checking here In the Magento admin console, go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods. Scroll down to Other Payment Methods > Apruve. Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, that is where it appears on my own test server.

Comment: Also is that enabled on app/etc/config.php. I guess it should be. If its there then can you just delete the entry from setup_module table and run php bin/magento setup:upgrade again and try.

Comment: I don't believe Magento Cloud lets you run 'setup:upgrade'  once code is deployed. And their file system is Read Only.